# MySQL Replication stop after a huge amount of transactions on Master

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-8.0

Running MySQL 8 for months now, without much troubles, I still have **randomly** some problem of replication between the Master and its Slave.

Problems means, all works, both instance works, still the Replication it self is broken, but without any reported errors.

```
mysql> show master status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             File: mysql-bin.003987
         Position: 82938366
     Binlog_Do_DB: main_db,old_db,metabase
 Binlog_Ignore_DB:
Executed_Gtid_Set:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

While I have this for the Slave:

```
mysql> show replica  status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             Replica_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Source_Host: xx.xx.xx.xx
                  Source_User: reporting-slave
                  Source_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Source_Log_File: mysql-bin.003987
          Read_Source_Log_Pos: 80302413
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.001414
                Relay_Log_Pos: 103664748
        Relay_Source_Log_File: mysql-bin.003949
           Replica_IO_Running: Yes
          Replica_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Source_Log_Pos: 103664533
              Relay_Log_Space: 4108295738
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Source_SSL_Allowed: No
           Source_SSL_CA_File:
           Source_SSL_CA_Path:
              Source_SSL_Cert:
            Source_SSL_Cipher:
               Source_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Source: NULL
Source_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Source_Server_Id: 1
                  Source_UUID: 553a1b76-ec6d-11ea-a311-fa163e097e80
             Source_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
    Replica_SQL_Running_State:
           Source_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Source_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Source_SSL_Crl:
           Source_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Source_TLS_Version:
       Source_public_key_path:
        Get_Source_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> SHOW RELAYLOG EVENTS\g
+------------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Log_name               | Pos | Event_type     | Server_id | End_log_pos | Info                                               |
+------------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| mysql-relay-bin.001416 |   4 | Format_desc    |         2 |         125 | Server ver: 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, Binlog ver: 4 |
| mysql-relay-bin.001416 | 125 | Previous_gtids |         2 |         156 |                                                    |
| mysql-relay-bin.001416 | 156 | Rotate         |         1 |   107184471 | mysql-bin.003950;pos=4                             |
| mysql-relay-bin.001416 | 203 | Rotate         |         2 |         256 | mysql-relay-bin.001417;pos=4                       |
+------------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I know how to fix it, by stoping the replication, then dumping again the master, and reimport the whole stuff, however, the Database is huge, even with an high speed connection between those 2 servers, it may takes over half an hour to reimport the Database on the Replication Server.

Here are my questions:

1. Is the command `SHOW RELAYLOG EVENTS` can really explain a replication from being stucked? It seems to be ok the `position` is really different between `master` and `slave`
2. Is there a way, to let MySQL 8 go forward and leave this state of not replicated any more?
3. It seems this issue occurs when I have to handle a large amount of traffic on the server (we are recording Live sessions for Sportsmen), but I still don't understand why it stops like that randomly. Is there anything I could change in the whole Replication Configuration, to prevent us from this issue?

Thanks for any tips

Comment: It's odd to see this with no error identified in any of the `Errno` results. Is there anything reported in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` that might point to the source of this problem? Does restarting the replica with `STOP REPLICA;` and `START REPLICA;` do nothing?

Comment: Restarting did not help anything.
The Var log says only: `2021-07-26T00:11:40.746693Z 3246 [ERROR] [MY-013131] [Server] Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size!` and also
`2021-07-25T16:59:30.627362Z 3228 [System] [MY-010562] [Repl] Slave I/O thread for channel '': connected to master 'reporting-slave@xx.xx.xx.xx:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.003987' at position 83504089`

Comment: What settings (in my.cnf, etc) are different between the Primary and Replica?